# Expand $5(x + \Delta x)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

During class the tutor expanded $5(x+\Delta x)^2$ as follows:

$$5x+10x\Delta x+5\Delta x^2.$$

However, when I expand it the way I know how (and check with Wolfram Alpha), it expands as follows:

$$ 5 x^2 + 10 x^2 \Delta  + 5 x^2\Delta^2.$$

Which is correct? If both are correct, how? How was the first expansion performed exactly?

Comment: You are correct; the tutor’s error is probably a typo more than anything else, an accidental failure to write the first exponent.

Comment: I suppose $\Delta x$ is a number instead of a multiplication of $\Delta$ and $x$?

Comment: Are the variables here $x$ and $\Delta$, or $x$ and $\Delta x$?

Comment: $\Delta x$ usually means a change in variable $x$ so it might be considered as a whole and and not as the product of two numbers/variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tutor intends $\Delta x$ to be a single value, not the product of $\Delta$ and $x$.  $\Delta x$ is usually some change to $x$, often rather small.  It may be a measurement error or a change in conditions.  With this reading, your tutor's expansion would be the same as $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ if the first term were $5x^2$